# Compare `Foo<i32>` and `Foo<u32>`

Tags: compare, rust, equality

Need realize the possibility of comparison `Foo<i32>` and `Foo<u32>`.

```
struct Foo<T> {
    id: usize,
    data: T
}
impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn new_i32(i: i32) -> Foo<i32> {
        Foo {
            id: 0,
            data: i
        }
    }
    fn new_u32(u: u32) -> Foo<u32> {
        Foo {
            id: 1,
            data: u
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that trait `PartialEq` can only compare the **same** types.

```
impl<T> PartialEq for Foo<T> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.id == other.id
    }
}
```

And this dont work:

```
let a = Foo::new_u32(123);
let b = Foo::new_i32(123);
println!("{}", a == b);
```

Full code in [play.rust-lang.org](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=37aa9c840aad8311e5705d4ab8deb1e3&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem is that trait `PartialEq` can only compare the **same** types.

That's not true. It just defaults the `Rhs` to the same type as `Self`:

```
pub trait PartialEq<Rhs = Self> where Rhs: ?Sized {
    ...
}
```

Here's how you would implement `PartialEq` for `Foo<L>` and `Foo<R>` for any `L` and `R`:

```
impl<L, R> PartialEq<Foo<R>> for Foo<L> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Foo<R>) -> bool {
        self.id == other.id
    }
}
```

Note that I also had to change the `impl` block to fix some type inference errors. Final code:

```
struct Foo<T> {
    id: usize,
    data: T,
}

impl Foo<i32> {
    fn new_i32(i: i32) -> Foo<i32> {
        Foo { id: 0, data: i }
    }
}

impl Foo<u32> {
    fn new_u32(u: u32) -> Foo<u32> {
        Foo { id: 1, data: u }
    }
}

impl<L, R> PartialEq<Foo<R>> for Foo<L> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Foo<R>) -> bool {
        self.id == other.id
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Foo::new_u32(123);
    let b = Foo::new_i32(123);
    println!("{}", a == b);
}
```

Output:

```
false
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=51166880a9ab0c49d7650588c4ed8290&version=stable&backtrace=0